# Camcapture on Notebook with showing the video on Pepper. (Choreographe, Python)

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

I have a question about a programm with Python.
I must capture my Notebookcam with Pepper and show it on the Display from Pepper.
Now I have the Problem, the programming with Choreograph is a little bit different and I don't know how I can handle this Programm. I would be happy if you could answer.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific, your asking how to write an entire program, which is not really what SO is for. Do you have a specific line of code thats causing you troubles, or a particular fragment you cant get working?

Comment: Pepper's tablet is an android tablet, so you just need to do as you will have done to render a remote webcam to a tablet. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Choregraphe to retrieve the video remotely because the applications made using Choregraphe are run on the robot, not on your PC.

You need to write separate program on your PC to retrieve the video.